# Сессия в виде цифр

Tags: php

Вопрос впринципе вот в чем, видал на множестве сайтов сессию вида &ses=1234567... т.е сессию, состоящую из цифр. Пытался сделать подобное, но ничего не вышло! Хотелось бы узнать, каким образом можно реализовать это?

Comment: Помоему вы фигней занимаетесь

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, что именно не получается у Вас реализовать: как работать с сессией, содержащей определенное имя, или генерировать случайные числа. Ну вот пример, по крайней мере, создающий переменную и линк на страницу с &ses=1234567

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['ses'] = rand(1000000, 9999999);
echo "<a href=\"somepage.php?someresult=true&ses=" . $_SESSION['ses'] . "\">Link</a>";
?>
```

Уточните, что именно Вы ожидаете от &ses=1234567, для какой цели реализуете?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я вижу, это не сессия, а передача переменных способом GET. Пример на PHP

```
<?php
<form action="some_site.php" method="GET" name="form1" target="_blank">
<p><input name="name" type="text" size="20"></p>
<p><input name="lastname" type="text" size="20"></p>
<!--Кнопка -->
<p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Передать"></p>
</form>
?>
```

В строке появится типа `some_site.php?name=Jack&lastname=Dou&submit=%CF%E5%F0%E5%E4%E0%F2%FC`. Надеюсь, понятно. Прочитать данные можно через `$_GET`

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
echo 'Привет '.$name.' '.$lastname;
?>
```

Естественно можно вводить и цифры, и слова.

Comment: Нет. Совсем речь не об этом! Речь о том, как из стандартной сессии, сделать сессию ввиде цифр!

Comment: Что значит стандартная сессия? Такого понятия как стандартная ссесия не существует.

Сессия - это обычная переменная окружения и живет она пока открыт браузер. В эту переменную вы можете пихнуть все что хотите. Цифры, Имя, перечислите города вашей страны - это будут значениями вашей сессии.

Answer (score 0):

Задача сессии - это формирование уникальной последовательности, алгоритм используемый при вызове обычной сессии это гарантирует. Пляски с rand() нет.

Comment: Ну почему)

    function formatBy3($str) {
      $result = '';
      $c = strlen($str);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $char = ord($str{$i});
        $result .= str_repeat('0', 3 - strlen($char)).$char;
        }
      return $result;
      }
    session_start();
    echo formatBy3(session_id()); // 12418912391503250238140..., и это можно восставновить)

=) Мож у автора какой-то хитрый план, а вы сразу rand))

Answer (score 0):

В настройках PHP можно выбрать алгоритм шифрования и длину ключа. Только цифр у вас стандартными средствами не получится!

Answer (score 0):

почитай про hex :))) Любую строку можно туда вогнать..... и выгнать :D